# Subset a Dataframe by Dates

Tags: r, date, filter, subset

This should be easy but i can't figure out how to do it and I can't seem to find any specific guidance on the internet.

I have a dataframe.  One column has date values in char format.  And there is some other data.  Example:

```
  Date       Unit      Entries
07-01-13      A          37
07-01-13      B          25
07-02-13      A          43
07-02-13      G          45
07-02-13      B          23
...          ...         ...
```

I simply want to break these into separate dataframes - each dataframe consisting of all the data for one date.  So I would get:

```
  Date       Unit      Entries
07-01-13      A          37
07-01-13      B          25
...          ...         ...


  Date       Unit      Entries
07-02-13      A          43
07-02-13      G          45
07-02-13      B          23
...          ...         ...
```

I have a much larger dataframe with a years worth of data and I want to avoid any kind of manual date range specification.

I basically want to filter into different dataframes based on unique data value.

Is there a way to do this easily?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `split(df, df$Date)`

Comment: Thanks.  if I understand `split` correctly it returns a list of dataframes?

Comment: Yep, which is [the most useful format for a lot of data.frames](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050).

Comment: Thanks.  Your link:  "the most useful format for a lot of data.frames" is also very helpful